# I do not want that my child page inherits the link color (red) of the parent theme , how do i do that?

Tags: html, css, parent-child, inheritance

I don't want that my child page inherits the link color (red) of the parent theme, instead i want white colored links on my child page, what should i change in the html/css to make that happen?

parent page css

```
  a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:red;
   }

 a:hover{
  color:white;
   -moz-transition: all .2s;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  -o-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2;
   }
```

child page links

```
<div id="links">
<ul id="list">
<li><a href="url">bla </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a second CSS rule that is more specific for your `a` tag.

For example:

```css
#links a {
    color: white;
}
```

or

```css
#list a {
    color: white;
}
```

I would add these rules below the two that you posted in your sample.

However, you could also use a `class` instead of an `id` to make the CSS rule more generally applicable.

**PS**

If you are applying this to your Tumblr page, there may be other styles conflicting so you might have to make the CSS rule even more specific.  I would need the link to your Tumblr page to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Then just add a `white-links` class to any `a` parent and they will become white.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="links">
    <ul id="list" class="white-links">
        <li><a href="url">bla </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.white-links a {
    color: #fff;
}
```